# Subobjects(A) $\cong \operatorname{Hom}(A,\Omega)$ in a topos is a natural transformation?

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Let $C'$ be the category with objects $C$ and morphism the monic morphisms of $C$. In any topos, $\phi_A: \operatorname{Sub}(A) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_C(A,\Omega)$ and $\phi_A(m) = \chi_m$. This seems to also be a natural transformation since if $m \text{ monic} \in \operatorname{Sub}(A)$ and $n : A \mapsto B$ is monic, then $n\circ m \in \operatorname{Sub}(B)$ and $\chi_{n \circ m} \circ n = \chi_m$ Therefore, $\phi$ behaves like a contravariant functor since the $\operatorname{Sub}$ maps arrows by composing similar to $\operatorname{Hom}$ (only contravariantly).

Is this important/ does it get used elsewhere?

Comment: The directions of your morphisms are mixed up. Think through everything carefully and re-ask your question.

Comment: @ZhenLin I made some changes, is it legible now?

Comment: Well, it is a correct observation, but I don't think it is especially interesting. You can get rid of $\Omega$ and turn it into a statement about pullbacks: the pullback of $n \circ m$ along $n$ is $m$ again, which is what you expect.

Comment: I'm still confused. In the third line, "$m \circ n$" should be "$n \circ m$", right? And then what does it mean for the natural transformation $\phi$ to "behave like a contravariant functor"? Is the observation that, in addition to being a natural isomorphism between the functors $\mathrm{Sub}, \mathrm{Hom}_C(-,\Omega) : C^\mathrm{op} \to \mathsf{Set}$, there are also functors $\mathrm{Sub}, \mathrm{Hom}_C(-,\Omega): C' \to \mathrm{Set}$, which are the same on objects as the previous functors, and which are naturally isomorphic via the same maps $\phi$?

Comment: You are correct on both counts, @tcamps. However, I am not sure if Sub is a functor from $C$ since only monic arrows compose well. Function composition and transitioning to composition of arrows always messes me up...